# Symfony's Assetic duplication of third party sources?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm reading through the below link to try and figure out Assetic:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

It sounds very good but I'm trying to understand how it works and I can't find any information about how it would handle duplicate third party sources across different bundles. For example, if different bundles which all called the bootstrap js/css scripts as below - would the final consolidated file have multiple copies of each?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assetic doesn't manage CSS/JS files that are loaded remotely, it only manages the CSS/JS files that you store locally in your project.  So there won't be any consolidation on those.  You wouldn't want that consolidation anyway because those 3rd-party files on CDNs will be cached on a user's device and load from that cache without having to download every time.